# Stop worker role instance from Windows Azure Management Portal

Tags: azure

There is probably an easy solution to this, but my searching has been unable to find it.

In my Azure solution, I have a worker role with two instances that are pulling messages off a queue for processing. For debugging purposes, I want to temporarily stop those instances.

If I click on `Cloud Services`, and then click `Instances`, I see my two instances which are running, but there doesn't appear to be any way to pause/stop/turn them off. Any ideas as to how I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there doesn't appear to be any way to pause/stop/turn them off

You're correct in your observation because you can't pause/stop/turn off a specific instance. You could stop or turn off an entire cloud service but not an individual instance. You could however delete a particular instance but that's not something you have in mind if I understand correctly.

> Any ideas as to how I can?

Do take a look at this blog post: http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/temporarily-taking-a-cloud-service-role-instances-off-of-the-load-balancer/. Basically the trick is to make an instance `Busy` so that Azure load balancer does not send request to that instance.

Comment: Note that setting an instance to Busy will take it out of LB rotation, but won't do anything to a worker role that is polling for messages in a queue.  You have a couple options: 1) Add custom code so that you can indicate via a config change that your role should stop getting messages, 2) RDP to the VM and stop WaWorkerHost from running.  There are various ways to do #2, but the easiest is to RDP to the VM, download AzureTools, in AzureTools download debugging tools, attach WinDBG to WaWorkerHost.exe and leave it broken in.